# how to get  json response in ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

url : `http://localhost/test-mobile/log.php?username=&password=pass`

```
$.ajax({
       url:url,
       type:'POST',
       data:{message:message},
       dataType:'json',
       json:'members',
       success:successData,
       error:function(){
        alert("error")
       }
      });
      function successData(data){
    var response=data.message;
    alert(response);
}
```

json response is `{"members":{"httpCode":"400","message":"Username missing"}}`

PHP code is given below:

```
<?php
    require_once("class/clsdatabase.php"); //Connect to SQL 

$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

    //Check Username
    if($username == '') {
        $user = 'Username missing';
        $success = true;
        $status = array("httpCode"=>"400", "message"=>$user);
        //return $status;
    }

    //Check Password
    if($password == '') {
        $pass = 'Password missing';
        $success = true;
    }


    //Create SELECT query
    $qry = "select * from user_register where emp_code='$username' AND emp_password='$password' AND active='1';";

    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    $te = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($te == 0 && $username != '' && $password != '') {
        $both = 'Invalid username or password';
        $success = true;
    }


    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the registration form
    if($te != 0 && $username != '' && $password != '') {

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $name = $row['emp_code'];
        $success = true;
        $status = array("httpCode"=>"400", "message"=>$name);
        //return $status;
    }

//echo $_GET['callback']. '(' . json_encode($status) . ');';    
echo '{"members":'.json_encode($status).'}';

?>
```

alert a json response

Comment: Please do some code formatting.

Comment: Please put question in a Proper format. Now no one can even guess that what it is!!!

Comment: He's just a new user, dont need to downvote :(

Comment: you are not passing the username and password to the url

Answer (score 3):

I would split the pages up into two.  One file called ajax.php and another called index.php.

Your index.php will look something like.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

     postData={ajax:"testing",id:'123'};

     $.post('ajax.php', postData , function (data) {
       alert(data);
     });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And your ajax.php file will look something like

```
<?php

// its important that this file only outputs json or javascript 
// content and nothing else.

if(isset($_REQUEST['ajax'])){

  $ajaxRequest =  $_REQUEST['ajax'];

  if($ajaxRequest == 'testing'){

  // do some php stuff here -- if you look at the above example we sent an id variable
  $sql = "SELECT FROM table WHERE id = {$_REQUEST['id']}";

  $results = query($sql);

  echo json_encode($results);
  exit; // exit the script here so that only the ajax stuff is output

  }

}
```

Comment: Haven't done PHP in a while, but I think you may need to json_decode($_REQUEST) -- but yeah, good advice. Start simple.

Comment: no you dont need to decode it as your not reading json data on the ajax.php page its just a normal http request.  you are outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery .ajax function automatically decodes the JSON object if the dataType:'json' parameter is set (which it is in his query).  So the 'data' variable passed to the success() function will already be a javascript object.

To access the 'message' value, you would use "data.members.message" since the 'members' object contains the 'message' value.